# Regex pattern matching for XSLT 2.0

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0

I have a string that needs to be parsed using XSLT 2.0

Input string

`Hoffmann, R&#252;diger (Universtiy-A, SomeCity, (SomeCountry); University-B, SomeCity, (SomeCountry)); Author, X; Author, B. (University-C, SomeCity (SomeCountry))`

Expected output 
`Hoffmann, R&#252;diger (Universtiy-A, SomeCity, (SomeCountry); University-B, SomeCity, (SomeCountry))` 
`Author, X` 
`Author, B. (University-C, SomeCity (SomeCountry))`

The structure is - author name, followed by his university. But, one author could have two universities. And the delimiter between universities and between two sets of author is the same one. (semi-colon in this case).

I need to split it based on the delimiter for author-affiliation group, ignoring the semicolon between affiliations and also in author names (HTML entities).

I believe it can be done with the help of regex, but I have not much experience building regex myself.

Comment: So, you want to find `;` characters followed by a space, as in `; `?

Comment: @itsbalur what is a regex engine you are using ?

Comment: I have this answer from a previous post (very similar but without the case of author names having semi colons) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959720/split-string-following-a-pattern-using-xslt-2-0. I need the modified regex which would fit the new requirement

Comment: @tchelidze: the XSLT parser is Saxon

Comment: Which version of Saxon exactly do you use or can you use? I think it would be better to parse the input with the numeric character references as XML first, to not have to deal with them when writing the regular expression.  Saxon 9.7 HE(or PE and EE of course) would support `parse-xml` or `parse-xml-fragment` http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/fn/parse-xml-fragment.html.

Comment: How do you pass in that input anyway to Saxon, as part of an XML document, or using a string parameter, using `unparsed-text`?